# count the number of times a value appears in a math equation

Tags: math, polynomial-math

how to count the number of times a value appears in a math equation?
explanation:
suppose in an equation of a circle i want to calculate how many timw does the value of y=5 occurs.
or in a parabola how many times the equation gives the value of 5;
or how many times does sin(x) have the value of 1 in a given range

is it possible to get the count mathematically rather than computing iteratively or recursively

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Answer (score 3):

To find the number of times an equation equals 5, is equal to finding the number of roots for the equation minus 5.

There are no general methods for finding roots of an arbitrary function. You could use Newtons method with different start values to *search* for roots, but you can't in general tell whether or not you've found all of them.

Comment: yes but i wanted the count of roots...
newtons method wont help me there

Comment: There is no way to count the number of roots of an arbitrary equation. If you restrict yourself to polynomials there are a few techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Depending what you are trying to do, it may be possible to use numerical continuation. It is not easy to implement, but there are good [software tools](http://www.netlib.org/contin/index.html) available (Pitcon is very reliable).

In general, numerical continuation attempts to solve a system of N variables and N-1 nonlinear equations. The N-th variable is allowed to vary over a domain, and the continuation method yields all the solutions to the system along a curve. A good continuation method can follow the curve going back and forth, and you can then see the resulting plot and determine the number of roots for a given parameter.

Again, numerical continuation is not easy, and it can be difficult to provide initial guesses, but it is a well known method.

Comment: yes thats true but i was wondering whether the count could be performed mathematically rather than computed iteratively...
in short a formula for the count of roots

Comment: Not in general - there will always be implicit equations whose solution can only be found via iteration. Some simple cases have well known solutions, so sin(k*pi) = 0 for k in 0, 1, ...